Replace a cell in a column based on a cell in another column in a polars DataFrame
Consider the following pl.DataFrame:
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "symbol": ["s1", "s1", "s2", "s2"],
        "signal": [0, 1, 2, 0],
        "trade": [None, 1, None, -1],
    }
)

shape: (4, 3)
┌────────┬────────┬───────┐
│ symbol ┆ signal ┆ trade │
│ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---   │
│ str    ┆ i64    ┆ i64   │
╞════════╪════════╪═══════╡
│ s1     ┆ 0      ┆ null  │
│ s1     ┆ 1      ┆ 1     │
│ s2     ┆ 2      ┆ null  │
│ s2     ┆ 0      ┆ -1    │
└────────┴────────┴───────┘

Now, I need to group the dataframe by symbol and check if the first row in every group in column signal is not equal to 0 (zero). It this equals to True, I need to replace the corresponding cell in column trade with the value in the cell in signal.
Here's what I am actually looking for:
shape: (4, 3)
┌────────┬────────┬───────┐
│ symbol ┆ signal ┆ trade │
│ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---   │
│ str    ┆ i64    ┆ i64   │
╞════════╪════════╪═══════╡
│ s1     ┆ 0      ┆ null  │
│ s1     ┆ 1      ┆ 1     │
│ s2     ┆ 2      ┆ 2     │ <- copy value from the ``signal`` column
│ s2     ┆ 0      ┆ -1    │
└────────┴────────┴───────┘


Would the value of the trade column always be missing here?

Not necessarily.

Ok good. I was just asking because otherwise, one would be able to simplify with pl.Expr.fill_null.

For this, a when-then-otherwise construct may be used.

We create a condition that evaluates to True exactly for the first rows (create index on the fly using pl.int_range) in each group with signal not equal to 0.
Based on that condition, we either select the value in the signal or trade column.

df.with_columns(
    trade=pl.when(
        pl.col("signal") != 0,
        pl.int_range(pl.len()) == 0,
    ).then("signal").otherwise("trade").over("symbol")
)

shape: (4, 3)
┌────────┬────────┬───────┐
│ symbol ┆ signal ┆ trade │
│ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---   │
│ str    ┆ i64    ┆ i64   │
╞════════╪════════╪═══════╡
│ s1     ┆ 0      ┆ null  │
│ s1     ┆ 1      ┆ 1     │
│ s2     ┆ 2      ┆ 2     │
│ s2     ┆ 0      ┆ -1    │
└────────┴────────┴───────┘


This is a clever solution! I was wondering if we can work with first() instead of creating the index on the fly?

@Andi Not as far as I know. We could use pl.Expr.first if we wanted to condition on the value of the first row. However, we'd like to condition on currently processing the first row (e.g. "being" in the first row).

@Andi If you had an index column or any column that contains unique values within each symbol group, you could replace the condition with pl.col("index") == pl.col("index").first(). In the solution above, we create the index ourselves and compre with the first value of our index, which is always 0.

That sounds reasonable. Thanks!

You can use .is_first_distinct() to identify the desired rows.
df.with_columns(pl.col.symbol.is_first_distinct().alias("checkme"))

shape: (4, 4)
┌────────┬────────┬───────┬─────────┐
│ symbol ┆ signal ┆ trade ┆ checkme │
│ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---     │
│ str    ┆ i64    ┆ i64   ┆ bool    │
╞════════╪════════╪═══════╪═════════╡
│ s1     ┆ 0      ┆ null  ┆ true    │
│ s1     ┆ 1      ┆ 1     ┆ false   │
│ s2     ┆ 2      ┆ null  ┆ true    │
│ s2     ┆ 0      ┆ -1    ┆ false   │
└────────┴────────┴───────┴─────────┘

And use as part of the when/then logic:
df.with_columns(
    pl.when(
       pl.col.symbol.is_first_distinct(),
       pl.col.signal != 0
    )
    .then("signal")
    .otherwise("trade")
    .alias("trade")
)

shape: (4, 3)
┌────────┬────────┬───────┐
│ symbol ┆ signal ┆ trade │
│ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---   │
│ str    ┆ i64    ┆ i64   │
╞════════╪════════╪═══════╡
│ s1     ┆ 0      ┆ null  │
│ s1     ┆ 1      ┆ 1     │
│ s2     ┆ 2      ┆ 2     │
│ s2     ┆ 0      ┆ -1    │
└────────┴────────┴───────┘


that's a good one.

Using cum_count over symbol and when:
df.with_columns(
    trade=pl.when(
        pl.cum_count('symbol').over('symbol').eq(1),
        pl.col('signal') != 0,
    )
    .then('signal')
    .otherwise('trade')
)

Output:
┌────────┬────────┬───────┐
│ symbol ┆ signal ┆ trade │
│ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---   │
│ str    ┆ i64    ┆ i64   │
╞════════╪════════╪═══════╡
│ s1     ┆ 0      ┆ null  │
│ s1     ┆ 1      ┆ 1     │
│ s2     ┆ 2      ┆ 2     │
│ s2     ┆ 2      ┆ -2    │
└────────┴────────┴───────┘


Using pl.cum_count only works if trade is guaranteed to be missing in the first row within each symbol group.

@Hericks indeed it's different from pandas's, then pl.cum_count('symbol').over('symbol').eq(1) should be fine?

Yes, in pandas this would work as cum_count creates a row index. In polars, it counts non-null elements. As we cannot be sure that the first element in each group is (not) equal to null, it cannot be used here. Instead, pl.int_range(pl.len()) can be used to create the row index.

I guess the equivalent of groupby.cumcount is int_range.over ;)
